# How to get all combinations of an array with generic size?

Tags: arrays, generics, recursion, combinations

I have an array like [1,-1,0] and I want to generate all combinations vector with this array items and generic size. For example size: 3 and out put: 
[1 1 1] [1 1 0] [1 1 -1] ... [0 0 0] or size: 4 and output: [1 1 1 1] [1 1 1 0] ...
[0 0 0 0] or another size and another array.

How to make it with generic array and generic size?

Comment: Can you specify which programming language are you using to do this? And also, please add snippets of what you have tried

Comment: C# or Javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned JavaScript so here's one way using generators

```js
const append = (xs, x) =>
  xs .concat ([ x ])

const ncomb = function* (n, xs = [])
{ const gen = function* (n, acc)
  { if (n === 0)
      yield acc
    else
      for (const x of xs)
        yield* gen (n - 1, append (acc, x))
  }
  yield* gen (n, [])
}

const data =
  [ 1, 2, 3 ]

const print = (...xs) =>
  console.log (...xs.map (x => JSON.stringify (x)))

print
  ( Array.from (ncomb (0, data))
    // [[]]
    
  , Array.from (ncomb (1, data))
    // [[1],[2],[3]]
    
  , Array.from (ncomb (2, data))
    // [[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[2,1],[2,2],[2,3],[3,1],[3,2],[3,3]]
    
  , Array.from (ncomb (3, data))
    // [[1,1,1],[1,1,2],[1,1,3],[1,2,1],[1,2,2],[1,2,3],[1,3,1],[1,3,2],[1,3,3],[2,1,1],[2,1,2],[2,1,3],[2,2,1],[2,2,2],[2,2,3],[2,3,1],[2,3,2],[2,3,3],[3,1,1],[3,1,2],[3,1,3],[3,2,1],[3,2,2],[3,2,3],[3,3,1],[3,3,2],[3,3,3]]
  )
```

Above the combinations increment the rightmost element, but this ordering can be changed. If you change the `append` operation to `prepend` you will generate combinations where the leftmost element increments instead –

```js
const prepend = (xs, x) =>
  [ x ] .concat (xs)

print
  ( Array.from (ncomb (3, data))
    // [[1,1,1],[2,1,1],[3,1,1],[1,2,1],[2,2,1],[3,2,1],[1,3,1],[2,3,1],[3,3,1],[1,1,2],[2,1,2],[3,1,2],[1,2,2],[2,2,2],[3,2,2],[1,3,2],[2,3,2],[3,3,2],[1,1,3],[2,1,3],[3,1,3],[1,2,3],[2,2,3],[3,2,3],[1,3,3],[2,3,3],[3,3,3]]
  )
```