# Recursive method to finding the k element subsets of a set with n elements

Tags: recursion

Consider the problem of finding the k element subsets of a set with n elements. Write a recursive function that takes an array of integers representing the set, the number of integers in the set (n), and the required subset size (k) as input, and displays all subsets with k elements on the screen. You may assume that the elements in the array have unique values. For example, if the array (set) contains the elements [ 8 2 6 7 ], n is 4, and k is 2, then the output is 82 86 87 26 27 67.

Can you help me with this, at least tell what way should I follow?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get all combinations of an array with generic size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53098328/how-to-get-all-combinations-of-an-array-with-generic-size)

Answer (score 0):

The type of thing you're talking about is a **combination&&.
There's a recursive definition of the calculation tucked in the middle of the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Number_of_k-combinations).

$$\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n-1}{k-1}+\binom{n-1}{k}$$

Figuring out what your base cases are might be tricky, but I think everything you need is there.

Answer (score 0):

I would've right something like this:

```
subset ( numbers, n, k, index)
{
   if (index < n) // end for the recursion. passed through all elements
   {
      if (k == 0) // end for the recursion. no more elements needed
         print ' '
      else
      {
         print numbers[index]
         subset(numbers, n, k-1, index+1) // uses the number in the current index

         subset(numbers, n, k, index+1)   // doesn't use the number in the current index
      }
   }

call subset(numbers, n, k, 0) to start
```

notice that because order doesn't play a role in sets, its enough to pass over the elements in one direction